# bootstrap with Jquery 1.3?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

We have a project which uses JQuery 1.3 already, plan is to include Bootstrap in same. Want to ask does Bootstrap work fine with all JQuery versions, particularly jquery 1.3 ?

Thanks

Comment: Gentalman can I ask why down vote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

> All plugins require the latest version of jQuery to be included.

So i think JQuery 1.3 is really too old to works with Jquery plugins and JS components.
Anyway, you can customize Bootstrap to use just the pure CSS components, common CSS, basic and responsive utilities... or migrate to the last JQuery version.